# showing blocks with jquery that are not display:"block"

Tags: jquery

How can I show an item with jQuery, using `slideToggle`, `fadeIn`, or a similar function, that is *initially* hidden and also uses a css attribute *besides* `display:block`?  I know I can add `style="display:none"` in the html and style the css as I'd like it when visible, but is there a way that uses only css?  Or a another way that has advantages? Having to use this technique to "trick" jQuery into using `display:inline` when it shows the element is not intuitive and might be hard to debug later.  Here is an example using the trick (I am keeping both divs inline, even after the second is displayed).

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYsnd/)***

```
<div id="a">hello</div>
<div id="b" style="display:none">world</div>
<button>show world</button>​
```

js:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#b").fadeIn();
});​
```

css:

```
div{
   display:inline;    
}​
```

Comment: you could use the [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functionality of jquery. 
http://jsfiddle.net/JYsnd/2/

Comment: You didn't read the question-I already know about those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the other answerers, but after some more research I think I've found an answer that's slightly cleaner.  Just modify the `fadeIn` statement with a call to `css(display:whatever)` in order to modify the outcome.  Since `fadeIn` and the other jQuery effects are asynchronous, it shouldn't cause any graphical glitches.  With this method, the css only affects initial styling, there are no style attributes in the html, and the intent and effect of the jQuery statement is obvious.  Thanks to jQuery forum user godsbest for the idea.

***[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYsnd/6/)***

```
<div id="a">hello</div>
<div id="b">world</div>
<button>show world</button>​
```

js:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#b").fadeIn().css("display","inline");
});​
```

css:

```
#a{
   display:inline;    
}
#b{
   display:none;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/sechou/JYsnd/1/
HTML

```
<div id="a">hello</div>
<div id="b" class="hideme">world</div>
<button>show world</button>​
```

CSS

```
div{
   display:inline;    
}​
.hideme{
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: +1 This does seem to work, although I'm still not completely happy.  Does jQuery use specificity, or just look at classes and id styles? It also doesn't seem to work in all cases -- http://jsfiddle.net/JYsnd/5/. In this example display:block gets used, when inline was expected.

Comment: css means Cascading Style Sheets. The first div{} would be override.

Comment: I'm familiar with the concept, but I don't see why my method doesn't work while yours does--you are using css's overwriting property too.

Comment: I just review jquery code. If the css("display") is "inline" when "none" is removed, jquery will display element with "inline".

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to avoid using `display: inline` you could position the 2 divs individually to display correctly using `float: left`.

Using a class for hiding the div would also help to debug your code later on.

See the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/bq9Hn/

If you are trying to avoid using display:none and display:block altogether then you could use `z-index` to hide the div in the background and then bring it to the front by setting a higher `z-index` value. eg.

http://jsfiddle.net/8xjEz/2/

Comment: I want to use display: inline, and I AM trying to use fadeIn or slideToggle.   However, +1 since solution number 2 is a partial solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are asking to have. You don't need HTML. Just keep it both inline and hidden with a comma.

CSS:

```
div{display:inline,none;}​
```